# Trying to find the number of x's that satisfies n + x = n ^ x fails with timeout

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation, java-stream, xor

I'm trying to solve the following problem from the section *Bit Manipulation* at the [Hacker Rank site](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sum-vs-xor) using new features of Java 8 such as `Stream`s.

**The problem description:**

> Given an integer, n, find each x such that:
>
> - 0 <= x <= n
> - n + x = n ^ x
>
> where ^ denotes the bitwise XOR operator. Then print an integer denoting the total number of x's satisfying the criteria above.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> - 0 <= n <= 10<sup>15</sup>
>
> **Sample Input:** 5
>
> **Sample Output:** 2
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> For *n = 5*, the *x* values *0* and *2* satisfy the conditions:
>
> - 5 + 0 = 5 ^ 0 = 5
> - 5 + 2 = 5 ^ 2 = 7
>
> Thus, we print *2* as our answer.
>
> **Sample Input:** 10
>
> **Sample Output:** 4
>
> **Explanation:**
> For *n = 10*, the *x* values *0*, *1*, *4*, and *5* satisfy the conditions:
>
> - 10 + 0 = 10 ^ 0 = 10
> - 10 + 1 = 10 ^ 1 = 11
> - 10 + 4 = 10 ^ 4 = 14
> - 10 + 5 = 10 ^ 5 = 15
>
> Thus, we print *4* as our answer.

**My code is as follows:**

```
public class SumVsXor 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        long n = in.nextLong();
        long count = LongStream.rangeClosed(0, n)
                               .filter(k -> k + n == (k ^ n))
                               .count();
        System.out.println(count);  
    }
}
```

The problem is this code doesn't pass all the test cases.

It works for small values of `n`, but for large values such as `1000000000000000` it fails due to timeout.

I wonder whether `LongStream` can't handle `Stream`s with that many elements.

Comment: So your question is "What are Java 8 streams for if it's possible for me to write slow code with them?"

Comment: So you learned that brute force can't be used in each and every case.

Comment: Streams are not magic. There is no reason the stream you created would work faster than a plain loop from 0 to n. With that in mind, you have to find a solution to the problem which is *better* than a plain loop from 0 to n. And then you decide whether that solution can be formulated as a stream.

Comment: You've jumped to a conclusion: You coded a solution with streams, the solution fails with a timeout, and you assumed the streams were the problem. Programming is many things, including checking your assumptions. (The brute force solution times out with a simple `for` loop, too, on high values of `n` such as `1111111113456` [test case #9], which is rather lower than your 1000000000000000.] It's nothing to do with streams.)

Comment: You could also ask what are functional languages for if they're not for solving algorithms. Java 8 streams are just more convenient way to work with collections without writing n functions and n^2 loops. If you are trying to compete in algorithm competition you can't expect that language will resolve problem for you.

Comment: I can see no reason to downvote it. One asks to get wiser.

Comment: i upvote this question - because this is not obvious. Totally agree with @Stormwind

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it is very inefficient. For the case of `n==1000000000000000`, your `Stream` pipeline is performing `1,000,000,000,000,000` addition and XOR operations, which takes a long time. Testing for each number between 0 and n whether `n + x == n ^ x` would take a long time even if you use a for loop instead of `Stream`s.

Instead of checking all the numbers between 0 and n, you should try to figure out a better way to calculate the required total number of x's. That fact that this problem appears under a "Bit Manipulation" section should give you a hint
to look into the bits of numbers that satisfy
 `n + x == n ^ x`.

Let's consider the case of `n==1000000000000000`. The binary representation of that large number is

```
0000000000000011100011010111111010100100110001101000000000000000
              ===   == = ====== = =  =  ==   == =
                 ---  - -      - - -- --  ---  - ---------------
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In order for `n + x` to be equal to `n ^ x`, `x` must have a `0` value in all the bits corresponding with the `1` bits of `n` (marked with `=` above), and either `0` or `1` value in the bits corresponding with the `0` bits of `n` (marked with `-` above). This doesn't include the leading `0`s (marked with `~` above), since x must be <= `n`, so any leading `0`s in `n` must also have a `0` value in `x`.

This means that the total number of x's for which `n + x == n ^ x` is
 2<sup>the number of `0`s in `n`, not including leading `0`s</sup>.

In the case of `n = 1000000000000000`, there are `30` such `0` bits, so the total number of `x`'s that satisfy the requirement is 2<sup>30</sup>.

Here's one way to compute the total number of `x`'s :

```
long n = 1000000000000000L;
int zeroBitsCount = 0;
while (n > 0) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        zeroBitsCount++; // counts the number of non-leading 0 bits
    }
    n = n >> 1; // divide n by 2 in order to examine the next bit in the next iteration
}
long total = 1L << zeroBitsCount; // the total is 2^(the 0 bits count)
```

Comment: Or just `1L<<(64-Long.bitCount(n)-Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(n))`. If `n` is not allowed to be zero, you could also use `Long.highestOneBit(n) >> (Long.bitCount(n)-1)`…

Comment: Mind that the total count is not necessarily fitting into an `int` (test it with `n=Integer.MAX_VALUE+1L` or even `n=0x4000_000_000_000L`), so you should use `long total = 1L << zeroBitsCount;`

Comment: or even `partners = 1;
  while (partners < n)
   if (0 == (n&partners))
    partners <<= 1;
   else
    n >>= 1;` - I guess I don't get what the bounty is for (can you elaborate on your goal in starting that bounty after the fact?)

Comment: @greybeard Just wanted to get more attention to this question (since it was badly received when posted) and to see if there are better answers.

Comment: `if ((n & 1) == 1) // n is odd` is faster than using the modulo operator to check if a number is odd (or even)

Comment: @Eran I came to the same output, but via a different logic. still 1+

Answer (score 2):

I came to the same result, but via a different explanation, so thought I might post it here.

Eran's answer got to the same conclusion that I did : to modify the zeroes in the binary representation of the initial number - that is pretty straightforward.

Let's suppose our number is

> 101010100

so it has 5 zeroes.

you need all the possible combinations of:

- a single zero
- two zeroes
- three zeroes
- four zeroes
- five zeroes

that is actually :

```
 comb(1,5) + comb(2,5) + comb(3,5) + comb(4,5) + comb (5,5)
```

that is a well known formula being equal to:

> pow(2,n) // where n is five in our case

from there the solution is obvious...

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    long n = in.nextLong();
    long count = 1L << (64-Long.bitCount(n)-Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(n));
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple question if you know little bit about XOR. I don't know much about java. But I can explain in python.

1.First convert the number to binary.
2.Count the number of zeros in that binary number.
3.print 2 ^ (number of zeros) and that's it.

Here is my python code.

```
n = int(input())
sum = 0
if n!=0:
    n=str(bin(n))
    for i in range(len(n)):
            if n[i]=='0':
           sum = sum + 1
    print(2**(sum-1))
else: print(1)
```

The reason to decrement the sum by 1 is, in python it convert the number to the binary as this format.  e.g: 0b'10101.